# Django REST Framework API schema generation with same URL prefix

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm documenting my Django application using `get_schema_view()` method, but when I open the Swagger UI all the URLs are placed under the same group.

My **urls.py** look like:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'stores', StoreViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('api/login/', views.obtain_auth_token, name='login'),

    # Documentation
    path('openapi/', get_schema_view(
        title='Title API',
        description='Some description goes here...',
        version='v0.1'
    ), name='openapi-schema'),
    path('docs/', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='documentation.html',
        extra_context={'schema_url': 'openapi-schema'}
    ), name='docs')
]
```

All the endpoints are placed under a group called **api** in the Swagger UI.

How can I specify the `api/` prefix while generating the schema in order to group the endpoints by model?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Grouping on OpenAPI endpoints with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830171/custom-grouping-on-openapi-endpoints-with-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The simple solution is to define prefix in settings.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX': r'/api/v[0-9]',
}
```

Answered here : [Custom Grouping on OpenAPI endpoints with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830171/custom-grouping-on-openapi-endpoints-with-django-rest-framework)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to an answer as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have installed the `django-rest-swagger==2.2.0` and had a similar concern about trying to group by tags for generics `ListCreateAPIView` and `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` of the rest framework. More info can be found in their docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#autoschema).

Here's an example of how it can be implemented to a tag named `"User"` for a user model views:

```
from rest_framework.schemas.openapi import AutoSchema


class ApiUserListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    schema = AutoSchema(
        tags=['Users'],
        component_name='User',
        operation_id_base='User'
    )


class ApiUserRetrieveUpdateDestroy(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    schema = AutoSchema(
        tags=['Users'],
        component_name='User',
        operation_id_base='User'
    )
```