# Separate by apps in drf-spectacular

Tags: django

Here it is the UI i can get from drf-spectacular redoc:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caw2B.png)
As you can see the only way to know the apps is from the names:
v1_foo_foodcourtrests_des
v1_ord_customer_basket_li
Here foo and ord are app names.

But I want to have a separator or something to separate these by the app names

Here is what I got so far and still no luck:
https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#settings

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830171/custom-grouping-on-openapi-endpoints-with-django-rest-framework)

one of the possible solutions is to use `tags` and `operation_id` in the `extend_schema` decorator to achieve the desired outcome.

for example:

```
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema

@extend_schema(tags=['Users App'])
class UserView(APIView):

    @extend_schema(operation_id='Get the user Details')
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # response
```

will result in:

[image]

another more streamlined solution if all of the urls have the same starting part like `/v1/` is to change the drf spectacular settings:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX': r'/v1/',
}
```

this will generate new sections based on each app initial url part, like foo, ord, etc.